# SVR, SVM, Gradient boosting and XGBoost runs forever [python]

Tags: python, svm, xgboost

I have a small dataset around 15,000 with 13 features.
all the inputs are integers without extremely large numbers.

I use these data to train classifiers such as SVR, SVM , XGboost etc with Gridsearch.

However each training process takes forever.(over 60 mins)

I have already scale my input data X but it still takes a lot of time.
also ,  from other post who had the similar problem, catch_size iin classifier such as SVC(cache_size=7000) has been added to train the model, but it seems helpless on speeding up the computation.

The data it self is very small so I feel very weird about this.

Here is an example of my code, if anyone can give me any suggestions I will appreciate very very much.

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor  

one_to_left = st.beta(10, 1)     
from_zero_positive = st.expon(0, 50)

params = {  
    "n_estimators": [100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190,     200],
    "max_depth": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "learning_rate": [0.05, 0.4, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4],
    "colsample_bytree": [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    "subsample":[0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
                      }

xgbreg = XGBRegressor() 
gs = GridSearchCV(xgbreg, params)  
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)  
y_gs = gs.predict(X_test)
```

the target variable y is a percentage in interger for regression problem;
binary data 0 and 1 for classification problem.

Comment: Cannot say about XGBoost, but svm based estimators works well with scaled data (mostly mean standardization). Look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling). Also post your data and complete code so that others can verify the running time on their machines.

Answer (score 1):

lets take look at the grid you are using:

```
params = {  
    "n_estimators": [100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190,     200],
    "max_depth": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "learning_rate": [0.05, 0.4, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4],
    "colsample_bytree": [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    "subsample":[0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
                      }
```

Total size of grid is :

```
from numpy import prod

grid_size_per_parameter  = [len(i) for i in params.values()]
### [8, 11, 9, 8, 8]

prod(grid_size_per_parameter)
50688 # this is how many models you need to train, not counting cv folds
```

You have a big grid. Lots of models to train.
I mean if this takes an hour you all still training 1000 models a minute :)

you can set `n_jobs= -1` to use all available parallel cores if you have multi-CPU machine.  But I would be smarter with the grid. Search a smaller space.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `n_jobs = 1` is a good solution , but a better way to deal with this is to use Randomsearch() instead.

It is proven that random gridpoint selection reaches to a better model faster and more effectively.